# Missing bundles in osgi framework

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to run the region digraph bundle of Equinox in Eclipse IDE. When I run the relevant bundle using start  command in OSGi command prompt, I'm getting an error saying 
**The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle; version="1.0.0"**. To find out the existing version in the framework, I tried the command **p org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle**. The result shows all the bundles in the framework. In that list **org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle** is not there. This is the same case for few other bundles such as 
**org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver**. Any helps about how to fix this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Eclipse are you using?

The `org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle` package was added in OSGi Release 4.3, and so you would need a version of Eclipse that supports that, which would be at least Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks a lot for the reply, after using Indigo and update the OSGi framework version, It works fine.